# How to add additional properties to be passed through sequelize object in express

Tags: express, pug, sequelize.js

So for example I have a sequelize model as follows:

```
// MyModel.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const MyModel = sequelize.define('MyModel',{
      foo: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  return MyModel
}
```

And then I use this model to express templating engine using controller as follows:

```
app.get('/foobar',async function(req,res,next){
    var myModel = await MyModel.findById('abcd1234');
    myModel.bar = bar
    return res.render('foobar',{
       myModel: myModel
    });
})
```

and my `foobar.pug` is like this:

```
html
   #{JSON.stringify(myModel)}
```

Apparently I can find the field called `foo`, but I can't get the field called `bar`, how do I pass this additional calculated field from my controller through my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason behind this is :**

```
var myModel = await MyModel.findById('abcd1234'); 
// will return an instance of MyModel not json

// So you can't just do
myModel.bar = bar;
```

**To make it happen ( Convert instance to JSON Object )**

```
var myModel = await MyModel.findById('abcd1234').toJSON();
// Now this will return the JSON object and not instance of MyModel 

// Now this will work
myModel.bar = bar;
```

**[toJSON()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-toJSON)** is sequelizejs's model's method , you can convert it via javascript function also.

**If you want to retain the sequelize object , retain it in different variable**

```
var myModelInstance = await MyModel.findById('abcd1234');

var myModel = myModelInstance.get({plain: true});
// OR
var myModel = myModelInstance.toJSON();

// Now this will work
myModel.bar = bar;
```

> These are the possible ways of doing , but because of lack of
>   requirement and code this is the best I can suggest , you can still
>   look into **[GETTER](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#getters-setters)** , if you need the extra fields inside
>   instance.

Comment: but i want to retain the sequelize object, i know you can overcome it using convert to JSON first, but i want to add the new property right to the sequelize object

Comment: @HansYulian , you need instance only when you still need to perform sequelize operation , after you get the result , like you get the record now you want to update or delete you can do that via instance , but I can't see any requirement of that through your code.

Comment: my real code is classified and confidential, i can't share it here, but i just address the problem i faced here

Comment: @HansYulian , please check updated answer , I think that can help you.

Comment: no, it still not, i will need to calculate some fields after the record is taken, then i need to use the record somewhere for further action. let me give you example: ```myModel.canEdit = myModel.isActive && myModel.totalContribution < 100```, after retrieving this record, i might update it if it's editable, or i just return it to the UI. i know the way that i can return to UI to show edit button and do process before it, but it means double work

Comment: @HansYulian , other way of doing is create a getter method, that might be your solution, as you are to sharing the full code no one can help you better than this , as I have answered the question , and also check the updated answer

Comment: oh, that getter method is the one i need, that will solve the problem! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in 2K22 and after :D,

you can use DataType.VIRTUAL when registering a field,

this allow predefining additional fields that will be used and keep it at serialize time but not persist into database.